# pandas: drop duplicate rows while keeping dummy variables values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, stack, pivot-table

I have the following sample of a dataframe:

```
child_id   feature_1   feature_2   feature_3   feature_4   feature_5
   10          1           0           0          0            0
   10          0           0           1          0            0
   10          0           1           0          0            0
   10          0           0           0          1            0
   20          0           0           0          0            1
   20          1           0           0          0            0
   20          0           1           1          0            0
   20          0           0           0          0            0
```

However, I would like to have this stacked dataframe, so children IDs are not repeated several times:

```
child_id   feature_1   feature_2   feature_3   feature_4   feature_5
   10          1           1           1           1           0
   20          1           1           1           0           1
```

As every row is different, I cannot simply drop the duplicates. Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: `df.groupby('child_id').sum()`

Comment: ^ Can add a `.clip(upper=1)` if need to ensure they are dummies or `.any().astype(int)`

Answer (score 2):

```
child_id  = [10,10,10,10,20,20,20,20]  
feature_1 = [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]  
feature_2 = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0]
feature_3 = [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]  
feature_4 = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
feature_5 = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(child_id,feature_1,feature_2,feature_3,feature_4,feature_5),columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F'])
df

df.groupby('A').max()

 #10       1    1   1   1   0
 #20       1    1   1   0   1
```